# How to get Application without activity or service?

Tags: android

In my app Application class is overrided and used for storing some data. Where needed I'm using `((MyApplication)getApplication()).someMethod()` and it working well. But I have one class where Activity is not available. In this class is available the context only. So I cannot call method `getApplication().`

How can I get Application object without `getApplication()` method? May be I can get it from Context or via static methods?

Comment: If you have context object in your class ,you can call context.getApplication();

Comment: This sounds like you should not be using a subclass of `Application`, but rather a regular Java static data member.

Comment: @andrewww, are you sure? I cannot find getApplication() method here, only getApplicationContext() or getApplicationInfo(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: @CommonsWare, as I know, regular singleton class in Android can be removed when the activity restarted.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I tell about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables

Comment: "as I know, regular singleton class in Android can be removed when the activity restarted" -- no, it is not. Static data members have the same lifetime as the `Application` instance, which is the lifetime of the process.

Comment: you can cast context to Activity and can call  getApplication() method